# Fourier Transform for IR spectroscopy: integral doesn't converge

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, chemistry

From Cozzi-Protti-Ruaro - Elementi di Chimica Analitica Strumentale, page 244:

> However, since the IR sources are of the continuous type, i.e. they
> emit over the entire spectral range, the interferogram is described by
> the equation

$$I(\delta) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} B(\nu) \cos(2\pi\delta\nu) \,d\nu$$

where

- $I$ = wave intensity
- $\delta$ = Michelson interferometer moving mirror offset (just like a phase constant)
- $B$ = maximum intensity
- $\nu$ = wave frequency

To obtain the inverse function, i.e. the intensity as a function of $\nu$, this equation is reworked with the Fourier transform

$$B(\nu) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} I(\delta) \cos(\delta\nu) \,d\delta$$

But when this integral does not converge: the test can be done in the case of a single frequency.
Could it be that the book has given a wrong formula?

Comment: I would assume that the factor $2\pi $ is missed in the second formula.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the book. In any case, even reinserting the 2pi factor, the integral does not converge equally.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How do you know the second integral does not converge?

Comment: I haven't had my coffee yet - but a purely single frequency isn't actually physical. What happens if you use a (somewhat) more physical Gaussian for $B(\nu)$? Normalize it to unit area then take the limit as it gets narrow. Also I'm confused because while *amplitude* (e.g. the electric field $E$) can be positive and negative, intensity (proportional to $E^2$) is always positive. So I don't understand why it's not either a) $E(\nu)$ for amplitude or b) $\cos^2()$. Fringes (be they from a laser or  a "white" light source) are always non-negative.

Comment: cf. [White light interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_light_interferometry) (there be math there)

Comment: @NinadMunshi can you try to resolve with WA or something similar?

Comment: @uhoh This fits better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_spectroscopy

Comment: @user3713179 Yes that's more helpful, and there's the $(1 + \cos(2 \pi \nu \delta))$ which (for want of a few 2's somewhere) is like $\cos^2$ and is always positive.

Comment: Even in the form $(1+\cos(2\pi\nu\delta))$ the integral still does not converge. Somewhere I read that it is actually a Fast Fourier Tansform: having never done it in my degree course, how do you apply the FFT in an equation like this?

Comment: @user3713179 now that's a separate and interesting question! But no, this question is not about an FFT, it's about an FT. FFT is a numerical trick to speed up a DFT (discrete Fourier transform) on a computer for discrete digitized data, where infinities don't exist. You Math SE question is asking why an actual mathematical integral diverges (without showing evidence of divergence?). I know it's challenging, but work hard to separate the real, mathematical Fourier transform from the discrete math tricks we do inside computers on sampled digital data.

Comment: Do you know the concept of Dirac's delta-function? In this (distributional) sense the integral converges also for the case of a single frequency.